# iOS: Can I get AVMetadataFaceObject for video from gallery?

Tags: ios, computer-vision

For real-time camera processing I use AVCaptureMetadataOutput for getting information about faces.
Can I get AVCaptureMetadataOutput (in particularly, AVMetadataFaceObject) for video from gallery?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`AVCaptureMetadataOutput` is, as the "Capture" in the name might suggest, only for use in media capture. It's a software interface for hardware-based detectors — e.g. the image signal processor in your device has fast (but not detailed or precise) face detection built-in so that the camera can do face-based autofocus.

If you want to process an already recorded video to detect faces, there are other APIs for that, leveraging software-based detection. The latest and best such API is the [Vision framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision) with its [`VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetectfacerectanglesrequest) and [`VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetectfacelandmarksrequest) classes.

[Here's an Apple sample code project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/tracking_the_user_s_face_in_real_time) showing the Vision face detection API in action for live video from the camera. (It also shows Vision's object tracking API to enable following the same face as it moves from frame to frame after detection.) The key difference to make it work with prerecorded video would be to replace use of the AVCapture system with an `AVAssetReader`/`AVAssetReaderOutput` to sequentially acquire pixel buffers from the video file and feed them to Vision.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I try to use Vision API but it is much slower than AVCaptureMetadataOutput and works with a little delay.